# Как запретить ввод собственного значения в строку(только варианты из перечисления) C#

Tags: c#, строки, enum

Допустим есть некое перечисление:

```
    public enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Yellow,
        White,
        Black
    }
```

И некая строка, которая используется для хранения данных и дальнейшей работы с ней

```
    public string Color { get; set; }
```

Подскажите, что нужно прописать в свойствах строки, чтобы варианты для строки можно было выбирать только из предложенных в перечислении, без возможности подставления в строку что-либо еще?

Comment: `public Color color { get; set; }`

Comment: @slippyk  и `public string ColorString { get { return color.ToString(); } }`

Comment: Строка должна быть доступна для редактирования, но подставлять в неё можно только из этого перечисления. Каким образом этого можно добиться?

Comment: @RistiRistin Что значит "можно"? А если свойству присваивается другое значение (не из `enum`а), что должно происходить?

Comment: должна быть ошибка, что другое значение туда подставить нельзя

Comment: @RistiRistin у меня вот какой впорос. как вы предполагаете вводить один из вариантов. например я начинаю писать "R", что должно произойти? Программа выдаст ошибку или позволит дописать "Red"? Может, если нужно однозначный вариант, использовать ComboBox?

Answer (score 2):

```
private string fColor = Color.Red.ToString();
public string Color 
{
  get { return fColor; }
  set 
  {
    string[] colorNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color));
    if (Array.IndexOf(colorNames, value) == -1)
      throw new ObjectNotFoundException(value);
    fColor = value;
  }
}
```